# Proof that a certain set is not nowhere dense

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

**Question:** Prove that the set

$N=\{f\in C([0,1])|f(0)=0\}$

is a nowhere dense subset of $(C([0,1]),d_{\infty})$, but not a nowhere dense subset of $(C([0,1]),d_{1})$, where $d_{\infty}(f,g)=sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$ and $d_{1}(f,g)=\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)-g(x)|dx$.

**My try:** I tried my best but **cannot prove the second part**. The first part of the proof can be found in my lecture notes, which is the following:

**Proof:** Let $f\in C([0,1])$ and $r>0$. We can clearly choose $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\delta>0$ such that

$(a-\delta,a+\delta)\subseteq (f(0)-\frac{r}{2},f(0)+\frac{r}{2})\backslash\{0\}$.

Note that $|a-f(0)|\leq\frac{r}{2}$ and $\delta \leq \frac{r}{2}$. Let $g\in C([0,1])$ denote the continuous function defined by

$g=f+a-f(0)$.

1. We claim that

$B(g,\delta)\subseteq B(f,r)$.

Indeed, choose a $h\in B(g,\delta)$, then

$d_{\infty}(f,h)\leq d_{\infty}(f,g)+d_{\infty}(g,h)\leq |a-f(0)|+\delta\leq \frac{r}{2}+\frac{r}{2}=r$.

That is, $h\in B(f,r)$.

2. Next, we claim that

$B(g,\delta)\subseteq C([0,1])\backslash N$.

Indeed, choose a $h\in B(g,\delta)$, then

$|h(0)-a|\leq|h(0)-g(0)|+|g(0)-a|\leq d_{\infty}(h,g)+0\leq\delta$,

hence

$h(0)\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)\subseteq (f(0)-\frac{r}{2},f(0)+\frac{r}{2})\backslash\{0\}$.

This means $h(0)\neq 0$ and thus $h\notin N$.

Comment: You assume we all agree on the meaning of $d_\infty$ and $d_1$?

Comment: Sorry I will now make it updated.

Comment: No worries. Also, you can use the \subset command for denoting inclusion of sets. For example $A\subset B$. If you want to allow equality you may use \subseteq, as in $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestions

Comment: It takes 13 characters in English to say you are welcome, but only 3 in Chinese.

Comment: For the second part show that $\cos 2\pi nx$ can be so approximated in norm $1$ by taking a small cutoff near $0$ to get $f(0)=0$ (in other words for fixed $n$ take $f_{\epsilon}$ linear from $0$ to $cos 2\pi n \epsilon$ and $\cos 2\pi  nx$ from then on; the usual bounded convergence theorem shows that the integral of the difference goes to zero with $\epsilon$; then the usual Fourier results show that the guys in the OP (which include $\sin 2\pi nx$) are $L^1$ dense in the space of continuous functions (first periodic and then using same cutoff, all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, $N\subseteq C([0,1])$ is nowhere dense w.r.t. to $d_1$ if and only if $\text{Int}(\bar N) = \emptyset$, where $\bar N$ is the closure of $N$ w.r.t. to the $d_1$ metric and $\text{Int}$ denotes the interior.

So let's start by computing $\bar N$, the closure of $N$ in $(C([0,1]),d_1)$ : I claim that $\bar N = C([0,1])$, that is, every continuous function is a $d_1$ limit of a sequence of elements of $N$. (Note that we see $N$ as a topological subspace of $C([0,1])$ here, otherwise the closure could be much larger)

It is clear (from the definition) that $\bar N \subseteq C([0,1])$. For the other direction, let $f\in C([0,1])$ be arbitrary, we will construct a sequence $(f_n)_{n\ge 1}\subset N$ such that $d_1(f_n,f)\to 0 $. Define for each $n\ge 1$ :

$$f_n(x):=\begin{cases}x n f(1/n) &\text{if } 0\le x\le1/n\\ 
f(x)&\text{if } x\ge1/n\end{cases} $$
For each $n\ge1$, we clearly have that $f_n$ is continuous and satisfies $f_n(0)=0$. Furthermore
$$ d_1(f_n,f) \le \int_{0}^{1/n} x n |f(1/n)|dx\le n\|f\|_\infty\frac{1}{2n^2}\to 0 $$
Where $\|f\|_\infty$ denotes the supremum norm of $f$ (which is finite since $f$ is continuous).

This shows that $\bar N \supseteq C([0,1])$ and thus $\bar N = C([0,1])$.

But now, because $C([0,1])$ is the whole space, it is open in itself and thus equals its own interior, which in particular is not empty. So we are done.

Comment: Thank you very very very much for this!

Comment: @宁博源 you're welcome ! please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the little "check" if your problem is solved.